# New to javascript trying to figure this out

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to make multiple lights activate on button clicks and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I thought I could make this into a function and then pass it the id name but it looks like it's not acting the way I want.

html

```
<div class="lights">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="yellow"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <button id="red_button"> Red Button </button>
    <button id="yellow_button">Yellow Button </button>
    <button id="green_button">Green Button </button>
</div>
```

css

```
.lights{
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.button{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#red, 
#yellow,
#green {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#red.active {
    background-color: red;
}

#yellow.active {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#green.active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

jquery

```
function click(e) { 
   $('#red,#yellow,#green').removeClass('active');
   $('e').addClass('active');
}

$('#red_button').click(click('#red'));
$('#yellow_button').click(click('#yellow'));
$('#green_button').click(click('#green'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0m9wos1r/1/

Comment: you are adding a class to an item with tag of `e`, which seems ... incorrect... and when you call a function with a passed parameter you need to wrap it in an anonymous function.

Comment: It would help if you'd describe more clearly what you're trying to accomplish. It's not at all apparent from your code.

Comment: you're passing in a variable e but adding class to a string 'e' instead of (e).addClass - though there may be more wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things. I wouldn't recommend naming your function after an event, although it should still work. The issue  with your code is that you're immediately calling the function, and in the function you quoted the parameter. Use this instead:

```js
function click(e) {
    $('#red,#yellow,#green').removeClass('active');
    $(e).addClass('active');
}
$('#red_button').click(function () {
    click('#red')
});
$('#yellow_button').click(function () {
    click('#yellow')
});
$('#green_button').click(function () {
    click('#green')
});
```

```css
.lights {
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.button {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#red, #yellow, #green {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#red.active {
    background-color: red;
}
#yellow.active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#green.active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lights">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="yellow"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
</div>
<div class="button">
    <button id="red_button">Red Button</button>
    <button id="yellow_button">Yellow Button</button>
    <button id="green_button">Green Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Off-topic, since when can we run code snippet straight from an answer?

Comment: @JeremyD - September 16, 2014 :) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/0m9wos1r/4/

2 issues you need to fix:

The function call within the click call.  Like so, using an anonymous function:

```
$('#red_button').click(function(){click('#red')});
```

The selector within the click function.  Like so:

```
 $(e).addClass('active');
```